# Nearest path in android google maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2, eclipse-adt

I made an application that makes evacuation route in the city, but I am confused how to choose the path to the nearest track ?

I to make a path from the first point (the user) to the second point (a safe place) but the second point is a line on the map that will be selected by the nearest path system.

Previously I had searched the internet for several methods, such as point to point, but if we use the method then we are determining its coordinates, while the chill is a system that determines the user's location coordinates of.

while the second point is a line that has a lot of coordinates. so in the end the system will choose the nearest lane of the many coordinates on the line

`so the questions`

1. How to make a line that follows the shape of the city streets?
2. How to make the path of the user's location closest to the line that we have provided earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do that one is to open google map and let google map handle it.
Below code

```
LatLng myLocation=new LatLng(map.getMyLocation().getLatitude(),map.getMyLocation().getLongitude());
                String url = getDirectionsUrlForMap(location, myLocation);              
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                        Uri.parse(url));
                intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                    startActivity(intent);

private String getDirectionsUrlForMap(LatLng dest,LatLng origin){

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "saddr="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "daddr="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;        


    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";         

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;


    String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?"+parameters;


    return url;
}
```

Another way is to show it on the map only [Check Here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/)

Comment: good one, but the destination have a lot coordinates and system has to choose one who have nearest path

Comment: by coordinate ,u mean latitude and longitude rite? if yes then u can easily find the shortest distance using the `Location.distance` method. then you can determine the shortest distance.The `distance()` method is not very accurate but it gives an approximate value.

Comment: U can use `distanceBetween`. I am sure this one will do what u want,check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]%29